# Spring-integration JMS Gateway number of connection

Tags: spring-integration

I have declared a  JmsOutboundChannel gateway as follow:

```
JmsOutboundChannelSpecTemplateAware templateAware=
     Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsConnectionChannelOneFactory)
            .headerMapper(getJMsHeaderMapper())
            .destination(serverProperties.getQueueName())
```

How could i increase/set the number of JMS connection to the messaging broker?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration; when using a `CachingConnectionFactory` (recommended), there is one connection and producers are cached (by default).

When using the provider's connection factory, a new connection will be used for each request (much slower).